# Spring Cloud Data Flow - Spring Batch Remote Chunking

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

How to do Spring Batch Remote Chunking within Spring Cloud Data Flow Server?

In my understanding - Remote Partitioning of Spring Batch can be done within Spring Cloud Data Flow Server using `DeployerPartitionHandler`.

But, How do we implement Remote Chunking inside SCDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special to run a remote chunking job on SCDF. All you need to do is to run both the master and workers as Task applications.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!! It helps!!